# How do I select a checkbox bound to a checkbox control from within c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

```
 BillingEntity = (string)rdr["BillingEntity"];
 string[] split = BillingEntity.Split(',');

 for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
     {
      split[i] = split[i].Trim();
      if (split[i] == "Clinic")
       {
        BillingEntityCheckBox.Items[i].Checked = true;
        Session["billingEntitySessionVar"] = Session["billingEntitySessionVar"] 
        + " Clinic";
        }
```

How can I check an item in a checkbox list from the underlying code?

I know with a single checkbox you use `checkbox.checked = true`. I had that working fine in my code, but I need to link the checkboxes together in a control so that I can trigger an event based on whether any of them has been changed by the user.

To give a little background, I'm pulling in data from a SQL database and outputting to the user interface through a `WebForm`.

Comment: You mean a `CheckBoxList` Control with an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event? That seems to be what you need bases on your (somewhat unclear) description.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity.  Thanks for the reply.  No, I'm not trying to change it based on an event like an OnSelectedIndexChanged, but rather based on the data I'm pulling in from my SQL database.  If the data from the database == "Clinic" for example, the Clinic checkbox within the BillingEntityCheckbox Control needs to be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the concept of databinding, is this what you're looking for?:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] myStrings = new string[] { "Example Value", "Not a Thing", "Many Things", "All the Thing" };
        cblThingy.DataSource = myStrings;
        cblThingy.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnPushMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //for all the things
        foreach(ListItem itemThing in cblThingy.Items)
        {
            //set a default of not selected
            itemThing.Selected = false;

            //if the text is the same
            //you can have any check you like here
            if (itemThing.Text == txtThing.Text)

                //say that it's selected
                itemThing.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

^The "code behind"

```
<asp:Label ID="lblThing" runat="server" Text="If you type the text and push the button the thing with select." />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtThing" runat="server" Text="Example Value" />

<asp:Button ID="btnPushMe" runat="server" Text="Push My Button" OnClick="btnPushMe_Click" />

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblThingy" runat="server" />
```

^The webform xml

Hopefully that helps!

p.s.  I think it would be a good idea to make a `readonly property` on the `BillingEntity` type, which would return a bool which does the check for `"clinic"` inside that class, making it more object oriented..

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't worked with data binding, but this looks like what I've been missing.  I appreciate the help!